# How to detect an overlapped time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, time, overlapping

```
**Schedule Table** 
Day nvarchar()
StartTime time(7)
EndTime time(7)
```

I want to detect if my inputs will be an overlap to any of the existing records.

```
Day -------- StartTime -------- EndTime
Sunday       10:00:00           15:00:00
```

This will not allow to insert a value of

```
Day -------- StartTime -------- EndTime
Sunday       10:00:00           11:00:00

Day -------- StartTime -------- EndTime
Sunday       10:00:00           12:00:00
```

and etc.

My code :

```
SELECT * FROM Schedule
WHERE Day = 'Sunday' AND
    NOT(StartTime < '10:00:00' AND EndTime > '11:00:00')
AND (StartTime < '10:00:00'  AND EndTime > '11:00:00')
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If there is an overlapped time, Then dont allow to insert the new schedule.

Comment: my code seems to be incomplete or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect overlapping periods with a where clause like:

```
where   p1.startTime <= p2.EndTime
        and p2.startTime <= p1.EndTime
```

If you're about to insert, you can for replace the rows from `p2` with the rows you're about to insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM Schedule
    WHERE Day = 'Sunday' AND
    ('10:00:00' < EndTime AND '12:00:00' > StartTime)
    ORDER BY ScheduleID
```